# What software(s) automate the ETL process when moving across Cloud platforms (e.g. Google, AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I've recently been tasked with moving a database from AWS to Google and was curious if there was any documentation or software that would automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Both cloud providers have this product: [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/dms/) and [GCP DMS](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration).

You may also find [this article](https://www.mouritech.com/article/migrating-data-from-amazon-rds-to-cloud-sql-using-dms/) to be useful.